# snapsvg - point of origin for scale/rotate after transform

Tags: snap.svg

I'm currently failing to understand how the point of origin works when scaling and rotating.

for instance, if I was to scale a 10x10 rectangle around its centre, I would expect I would have to get the rectangles last transform details (x and y), get the height and width of the rectangle and divide them by 2 and add them to the x and y but that just doesn't work.

Using SnapSVG I use the Snap.Matrix() method to create the matrix based on the previous transform:

```
var data = activeElement.data('originalMatrix');
var s = size/50; // size is a number from 1-100, defaulted to 50
var matrix = new Snap.Matrix(1,0,0,1,data.dx,data.dy);
matrix.rotate(data.rotate);
matrix.scale(s,s);
```

I under stand that for both rotate and scale methods accept a point of origin but I cannot work out how to calculate these values. Anyone know?

Comment: I would have thought that passing the BBox cx and cy value would be correct but still nothing

Comment: If you want to rotate about its centre, then el.getBBox.cx/cy should work, however, its important to figure if that itself will need to account for any transforms on the object. A basic jsfiddle would be useful as ever just to highlight with minimal code.

Comment: due to time saving I have used the last fiddle, same concept - http://jsfiddle.net/4eL3gstp/19/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think typically element.getBBox() suffices for most basic needs. But for more complex situations where there may be an existing transformation affecting the element, getBBox doesn't take this into account.

You could try

```
element.getBBox(1);
```

In the comments, the extra parameter is 'isWithoutTransform' which seems counterintuitive to me, but it does help a bit..

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eL3gstp/21/) (this may skip a little on drag, and I wonder if its due to offset of text element vs bounding centre)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eL3gstp/26/) May also help that has a plugin.

Ultimately for more complex interactions, I would tend to try not to rely on matrices (ie getting values from them), and control the variables yourself.

That would mean storing you rotate/scale/tx/ty and setting all of them yourself each time (ie one updateTransform method), via one Snap transformString (almost like a game).

I also started a toolkit a while back that was never finished, but has some useful bits if you ever want to trawl through (see snaptoolkit.js)

[snaptoolkit](https://github.com/ibrierley/snaptoolkit) in progress

Comment: Hi Ian, I do appreciate your help here. You first example does seem correctly rotate around the center but as stated, has side effects when using with scale as well. The second however doesnt work nor on fiddle, guessing because the plugin you wrote only returns an 'x' and 'y' (no cx/cy) guessing theses are still the pivotal points?

Comment: Odd, missed that, will scrap the 2nd bit for the moment.

Comment: out of curiosity, would it be easier if scaling and rotating to use css?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4eL3gstp/26/ is what I meant (still has leap problem which I think is the slider start). If its just visual and for performance I would actually use CSS. If you need interaction with the element (ie dragging it may introduce problems, but a separate slider would be ok), you may want to use svg. I think anyway, give it a go, I just can't quite remember if you still get proper bounding boxes on css transformed elements, plus check compatibility with browsers and css rotations etc.

Comment: I see where your coming from. Done a little test and the jump isn't down to the slider because if you drag it to 360, move it, drag to 0 move it there is no jump, its more erratic when vertical and less erratic the tighter the angle.